# Android studio randomly messes up gradle formatting?

Tags: android, android-studio

I will be editing a completely different file than the gradle file... then out of no-where all my objects won't be referencing their proper packages.
The gradle file's format gets messed up then throws this error:

> **Error:(57, 0) Could not find property 'provided' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@4bd72df3.
>   Open
>   File**

Running: Android Studio 2.1

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because of different package names defined. Packages in your project structure and the project ID defined in the gradle file might be different. This difference creates a problem during gradle build. Please paste your gradle file and also a screenshot of your directory structure.